# Why does the "Date Created" for the master database show such an old date (8 April 2003) in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, master-system-database

Why does the "Date Created" for the `master` database show such an old date?

I created the new instance today, not 2003.

[image]

Comment: Even my SQL Server 2016 install still shows that date for both `master` and `model` of  `4/8/2003 9:13:36 AM`

Comment: [Why does the SQL Server 2012 SA account always show up with creation date of 4/8/2003?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/91293) this question was here before.  but no answer

Answer (score 3):

This is just an educated guess mind you, but I would assume it is the date the new master database was created at Microsoft for SQL Server 2005.

I checked SQL Server 2012, 2014 and 2016 and all have the exact same date/time.

Comment: Agreed.  This is simply Microsoft's default created date since the mdf/mdb files for default databases (master included) are "Copied" during the installation process.